# Display data in JSP in 2 columns

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

For example, I have the following data:

1. africa
2. india
3. australia
4. USA
5. russia
6. etc.

This is the data I am receiving from database by the name "country".

Now I want to display this data such that it looks like this when the jsp is loaded:

[image]

The code I have written in jsp is as follows:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:forEach items="${country}" var="country">
                ${country.index} ${country.title}<br/>
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here I am get all names of country in a single row and in only 1 column. If I want to split the result to be displayed in 2 columns what should I do? what changes do I have to make to code?

Comment: image not showing

Answer (score 0):

Add another column and loop the rows (or loop over both columns if you want to do it that way too)

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${country}" var="country">
<tr>
<td>
${country.index}
</td>
<td>
${country.title}
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have N number of elements in `country`, then `halfIndex` is `N/2`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:forEach items="${country}" var="countrySetA" begin="0" end="${halfIndex}">
                ${countrySetA.index} ${countrySetA.title}<br/>
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:forEach items="${country}" var="countrySetB" begin="${halfIndex}">
                ${countrySetB.index} ${countrySetB.title}<br/>
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```